# Customize Visual Studio debugger to skip constructors

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I know it is possible to use .natvis files to customize how objects are displayed in Visual Studio while debugging.

Is there a way to modify the behavior of the debugger to step over certain member functions instead of stepping into them?

For example:

```
class pt{
    double x, y;
    pt::pt(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y){}  // <--- I don't want to step into this stuff in debugger
}

void some_function(pt const &point){
    // stuff that I want to step through in the debugger
}

int main(){

    // this will call the constructor for pt.  I want to step into 'some_function'
    // but I don't want to step into the pt constructor
    some_function({1, 2});  // I would like to step into this function without stepping into pt::pt first

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way with something like the natvis file to specify that I don't want to step into the constructor of a class like 'pt' in the example, when I step into the call to some_function?

(I know that it is possible to do step into specific, but I would like to not have to do that for cases like this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, but not with the same flexibility as `natvis` files.

Specifying the functions that the debugger 'skips over' is handled [via the `natstepfilter` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2019). Look for the section *Customize C++ stepping behavior independent of Just My Code settings* on the linked page:

> - To specify non-user code for all local Visual Studio users, add the .natstepfilter file to the`%VsInstallDirectory%\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers` folder.
> - To specify non-user code for an individual user, add the .natstepfilter file to the `%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\<Visual Studio version>\Visualizers` folder.
>
> A .natstepfilter file is an XML file with this syntax:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <StepFilter xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natstepfilter/2010">
>     <Function>
>         <Name>FunctionSpec</Name>
>         <Action>StepAction</Action>
>     </Function>
>     <Function>
>         <Name>FunctionSpec</Name>
>         <Module>ModuleSpec</Module>
>         <Action>StepAction</Action>
>     </Function>
> </StepFilter>
> ```

Currently this can only be done through the global Visual Studio configuration and, unlike `natvis`, cannot be included as part of the project.

There is already [an open issue in the Visual Studio bugtracker requesting support for per-project `natstepfilter` files](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/allow-natstepfilter-and-natjmc-to-be-included-as-p/561718).

Comment: I'm sure this is the answer, but I'm also sure I haven't been able to get it to work.  Do you know when the files are parsed by VS?  (Do I have to shut down VS to see changes, or do I just have to start a debug session over?)

Comment: When I figured out the correct file location (I have many remnants of old VS installations), I am getting it to work.  I am still struggling with the exact syntax required for certain things, but it is doing what I want it to do.  Thanks